# PHP Glob check if a file exists

Tags: php, glob

I am using the following function to understand if a file exists using `glob`

```
function eSetSplash($eID, $catID) {
    $splashscreen = URL_ICONSET . $catID . "/default_splashscreen.png";
    if (file_exists(glob(DIRECTORY_PATH_UPLOADS . md5($eID) . 'app/splashscreen_event.*')))
        $splashscreen = glob(SITE_URL .'/upload/' . md5($eID) . 'app/splashscreen_event.*');
    return $splashscreen;
}
```

I have two problems:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path
```

And also I am not sure if doing the following way will actually return the file path or if it is just my imagination :D

```
$splashscreen = glob(SITE_URL .'/upload/' . md5($eID) . 'app/splashscreen_event.*');
```

Comment: yes, $splashscreen = glob(SITE_URL .'/upload/' . md5($eID) . 'app/splashscreen_event.*'); this will find all files in  app directory starting with splashscreen_event

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) gets all filenames that match your pattern and it returns an array containing these names.

So instead of using `file_exists` (which expects a file path string and not an array), you can simply use something like:

```
$files = glob(...);
if (count($files) > 0)
```

to see if any files were found.

If you are sure your pattern will return only one file-name or less, you can use `$files[0]` or `reset($files)` to get the first element (if the condition is met...).

Comment: ok and for my second question. Does glob return also the matched filename if found?

Comment: You forgot an extra `)` behind `glob(...)`